# How to do a regular expression find and replace in javascript where it alternates 'replace' and 'find next'

Tags: javascript, regex

I can do it in Editpad by running a macro alternating 'Find Next' and 'Replace Current and Find Next'. However I've got a lot of regular expression text replaces to do like this so doing it for each one is time consuming. Doing it globally in javascript I can do if I want to do all of them at once but what I want to do is replace one, skip the next, replace the next, and so on to the end of the document.

I've tried googling the answer, but all the results are about finding and replacing every occurrence, which I already know how to do.

Comment: Please read the [Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). We can't help you unless you help us understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace()` is what you're looking for, [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```js
let replaceEveryOther = (string, replaced, repalceWith) => {
  let alternate;
  return string.replace(replaced, a =>
    (alternate = !alternate) ? repalceWith : a);
};

let string = 'thee doublee ee\'s neeeed to be fixeed soon!';
let fixed = replaceEveryOther(string, /e/g, '');
console.log(fixed);
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid having a helper function:

```js
let string = 'thee doublee ee\'s neeeed to be fixeed soon!';
let fixed = string.replace(/e/g, (function(a) {
  return (this.alternate = !this.alternate) ? '' : a;
}).bind({}));
console.log(fixed);
```